# Program does not print the correct sum value of prime numbers in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, primes

I am a beginner in the java language. I was tasked to create a matrix that calculates the total sum of all prime numbers from the randomly-generated numbers present in the matrix. However, my program does not print the correct value at all. What seems to be the problem with my code?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[][] = new int[5][5];
    Random ran = new Random();

    System.out.println("Print matrix");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 10 + ran.nextInt(50 - 10 + 1);
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            int num = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= arr[i][j]; ++k)
                if (arr[i][j] % k == 0)
                    num++;
            if (num == 2)
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nPrint the sum of prime no. in the matrix: " + sum);
}
```

Output:

```
Print matrix
33  11  41  43  38  
32  18  25  16  24  
40  16  11  18  11  
49  37  22  13  17  
10  45  30  13  37  

Print the sum of prime no. in the matrix: 234
```

The correct sum value should be `283` instead of `234`.

Answer (score 0):

### 49 is not prime = 7 * 7 = 49

For the input in the question, `234` is correct answer.
`11 + 41 + 43 + 11 + 11 + 37 + 13 + 17 + 13 + 37`

For the input in the image, expected result is correct
`11 + 47 + 19 + 17 + 41 + 29 + 37 = 201`

### Possible correction

1. Unless the matrix is a square matrix, it better to use the inner loop as `j < arr[i].length`
2. Prime number check requires division only till `floor(sqrt(num))`